# How to open modal bootstrap on checkbox click?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I've a custom checkbox. What I want is to to open a bootstrap modal when the checkbox is checked. I want a bootstrap modal to open just as when clicked a button. Hope you understood my question. How can I do it.

```
<div class="form-group mr-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#toddlers">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="toddlers" id="toddlers">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="toddlers">toddlers</label>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="toddlers" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="toddlersLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="toddlersLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working fine. What issue you are getting ?

Comment: No it is not working. when i click on checkbox I see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNqfZ.png. it show fade but it did not open modal

Comment: Please check the below answer. You had used same id. Because of that you were facing issue.

Comment: I have updated answer please try out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please checkout this code.  You had used same id **id="toddlers"** for the input box as well as for model.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-group mr-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#toddlers_1">
    <input class="" type="checkbox" name="toddlers" id="toddlers">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="toddlers">toddlers</label>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="toddlers_1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="toddlersLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="toddlersLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It did not event